# git clone giving a permission denied despite i can ssh into github

Tags: git, github, ssh, composer-php

We want to get some private repositories from Github into our development server. This works:

```
ssh -vT git@github.com
```

However

```
git clone 'ssh://github.com/company/repo -v' '/var/www/api/shared/vendor/'
```

doesn't work. It gives a `Permission denied (publickey)` error.

I'm using Composer to download the repositories.

Any idea on why it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not specifying the `git` user in your `git clone` command, whereas you did in the ssh command.

```
git clone git@github.com/company/repo
```

If you have trouble with this still, then you can set `GIT_TRACE=1` and re-run the command to see exactly what it is doing. More likely, you'll want to find an ssh command that fails and run it with the `-v` option to see why authentication is failing (wrong key, etc). Make sure you run both commands in the exact same environment.

More help is [available at Github](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey).

Comment: exactly, if I manually add git@ it works. Then, I have to talk with the developers from Composer to see why git user is not being used.

Answer (score 1):

you can  ssh-keygen ,copy your  ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub  content to github
Deploy keys